# Google translate API error

Tags: php, google-translate

I'm getting the following error while using the Google translate API:

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason":
>   "accessNotConfigured", "message": "Access Not Configured" } ], "code":
>   403, "message": "Access Not Configured" } }

I have enabled billing, activated the service, registered my API key and allowed the URL. After a bit of searching, no one has offered a conclusive answer.

The request to Google is called using CURL below:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?userIp=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '&key={MYKEY}&source=en&target=fr&q=hello%20there');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$info = curl_getInfo($curl_handle);
$error = curl_error($curl_handle);
```

Please note: I've put "{key}" to hide my key.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872731/google-translate-api-v2-403-access-not-configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case I solved it by adding this line before Curl exec:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'INSERT YOUR GOOGLE TRANSLATE API ALLOWED DOMAIN HERE');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it with your addition curl option :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Google Translation API docs](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#intro), it is a paid service. Quote:

> Google Translate API is a paid service. For website translations, we encourage you to use the Google Website Translator gadget.

Furthermore, [from the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq):

> Is there any free quota?
>       No, the Google Translate API is only available as a paid service. Please see Pricing and Support for more details. However we do offer the Google Website Translator gadget, which will translate your website without charge.

Also remember you need a valid application key, [as stated here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#auth) (You already have that).

So in short, I think it means you have not set up a pricing/billing plan for your application, yet.

Comment: In my question I stated "I have enabled billing". Thanks