# Google translate API not working

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

Hi I have a problem with [Google translate API](https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de)

While using the API key generated(For API key I have enabled billing, also IP's Referers are set to any IP and any referer.) for translation I've got the below error.

I have used the following code snippet provided by Google

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#auth

I always gets an error 403, Access not configured .

```
translateText({
      "error": {
      "errors": [
      {
         "domain": "usageLimits",
         "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
         "message": "Access Not Configured"
      }
      ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }}
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872731/google-translate-api-v2-403-access-not-configured

Comment: Did you added your Website address to your Google Translate API Account?